# How to compare string letters (javascript)

Tags: javascript, string, function, substring

Hey I've been trying to write a simple javascript function for comparing string letters but i can't make it work for some reason...here is the code.

```
function compare(wordOne, wordTwo) {
    if (wordOne.substring(0) === wordTwo.substring(0))
    {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
compare("house", "hell");
```

Comment: String letters -> What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: What is your code trying to achieve? You want to compare only first chaaracter?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring with `.substring()` you have the option to include where the substring starts and ends (if end is omitted, it will capture to the end of the string)... `wordOne.substring(0,1)`

Comment: Yes sorry i didn't explain it really nice...but yes i only need to compare first character.

Comment: You can also treat strings as arrays of characters. `str = "hello"` means that `str[1] = e`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want to compare the first letter of the two strings, you can use the following code

```
function compare(wordOne, wordTwo) {
    return wordOne[0] === wordTwo[0];
}
compare("house", "hell");
```

This condenses the `if`/`else` condition, as you are just interested in whether the first letters are equal - not in how different they are. 
You can also use `str.toUpperCase()` (or) `str.toLowerCase()` in order to make the comparison case insensitive.

As per @Josh Katofsky's suggestion, you can of course make this function more versatile by - for instance - adding a third parameter that tests the n-th letter:

```
function compare(wordOne, wordTwo, index) {
    return wordOne[index] === wordTwo[index];
}
compare("house", "hell", 0);
```

Comment: It would help make the code more reusable if you passed an `index` into the function and then returned `wordOne[index] === wordTwo[index]`

Answer (score 4):

To explain why your current code doesn't work, you need to pass a second parameter to `.substring` as the `to` value. `String.substring(0)` just returns the whole string after the 0th character, so the entire word. Fixed example;

```
function compare(wordOne, wordTwo) {
    if (wordOne.substring(0, 1) === wordTwo.substring(0, 1)) {
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}

compare("house", "hell");
```

You could also just use `wordOne[0] === wordTwo[0]`

Answer (score 2):

[substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) returns *the part of the string between the start and end indexes, or to the end of the string*.

If you want to compare only first character, use `charAt`

```
function compare(wordOne, wordTwo) {
   return wordOne.charAt(0) === wordTwo.charAt(0);
}
compare("house", "hell");
```

Or you can pass the index as the parameter

```
function compare(wordOne, wordTwo, index) {
   return wordOne.charAt(index) === wordTwo.charAt(index);
}
compare("house", "hell", 0);
```

Comment: you have luck that javascript is nice for the developer so that your second example would work as intended :P (add extra arg for clarity)